# how to set a weekday using java8

Tags: java, datetime, time, java-time

I have the following Joda-Time code which sets the weekday:

```
LocalDateTime localDateTime = new LocalDateTime(2016, 1, 1, 20,39);
LocalDateTime localDateTime1 = localDateTime.withDayOfWeek(7);
```

How can I do the same with `java.time`? I see that there is no `setDayOfTheWeek`:

```
LocalDateTime time;
time.getDayOfWeek()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`time.with(TemporalAdjuster)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#with-java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjuster-), specifying an instance of [`DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html), e.g.

```
LocalDateTime time1 = time.with(DayOfWeek.FRIDAY);
```

Answer (score 3):

You have several ways to do it:

```
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.of(2016, 1, 1, 20, 39);

LocalDateTime ldt1 = localDateTime.with(ChronoField.DAY_OF_WEEK, 7);
LocalDateTime ldt2 = localDateTime.with(DayOfWeek.of(7));
//Or, more readable, as suggested by @AndyTurner
LocalDateTime ldt3 = localDateTime.with(DayOfWeek.SUNDAY);
```

Answer (score 3):

It has no `setDayOfTheWeek` because `LocalDateTime` is immutable, so it has no setters to modify the object. (Joda Time classes are also immutable!).

Use this in Java 8:

```
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.of(2016, 1, 1, 20,39);
LocalDateTime localDateTime1 = localDateTime.with(DayOfWeek.SUNDAY);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `java.time` API does not have a `withDayOfWeek(DayOfWeek)` method. However it does have a general [`with(TemporalAccessor)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#with-java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjuster-) method that can be used instead:

```
LocalDateTime dt = base.with(DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY);
```

However, this leaves open the question as to which Wednesday is selected (it actually changes the date within a Monday to Sunday week). A better way is to use a [`TemporalAdjuster`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjuster.html) to make it more explicit:

```
import static java.time.DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY;
import static java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjusters.next;

LocalDateTime dt = base.with(next(WEDNESDAY));
```

This changes the date to the next Wednesday after the base date. See [`TemporalAdjusters`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html) to understand the options available:

- `next(DayOfWeek)`
- `nextOrSame(DayOfWeek)`
- `previous(DayOfWeek)`
- `previousOrSame(DayOfWeek)`
- `firstInMonth(DayOfWeek)`
- `lastInMonth(DayOfWeek)`
- `dayOfWeekInMonth(int, DayOfWeek)`